# provide a url to s3.upload_file()

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Currently I have the process of uploading files to s3 broken down to two parts:

1. download the file locally :

```
#downloads file from a url to local
def download_url(url, save_path):  
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(save_path, 'wb') as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024 * 1024):
            fd.write(chunk)
```

2. upload to s3 :

```
def create_aws_resource(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_default_region):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
    return s3
```

```
def save_to_s3(bucket,path,save_path,link_save_path, aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_default_region):
   s3 = create_aws_resource(aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key, aws_default_region)
   os.chdir(save_path)
   filename = link_save_path.split('/')[-1]
   s3_path = path+'/'+filename
   s3.upload_file(link_save_path, bucket, s3_path)
```

This process needs to be run on a server and hence I want to eliminate the first step of downloading locally.
Is there a way to directly store files (any files - .xlsx, .pdf, .ods, .xls, .html) to s3?
example : want to upload the file on http://seriestoriche.istat.it/fileadmin/documenti/Tavola_17.1.xls to s3 directly.
Any help would be highly appreciated !!

Comment: I don't see how you can completely skip downloading the file.... If you don't want to store the file on disk, you can keep it in memory and upload it to S3 from the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked like a charm for me !

```
def create_aws_resource(aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key)
    return s3
```

```
def save_to_s3(doc_url, doc_name,bucket,s3_path,aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key):
    s3 = create_aws_resource(aws_access_key_id,aws_secret_access_key)
    try:
        # Gets the file as an object
        response = requests.get(doc_url)
    except:
        print('File not downloaded from {doc_url}')
        next
    try:
        # uploads the file to s3
        s3.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(response.content), bucket, f'{s3_path}/{doc_name}')
        print(f'File downloaded from {doc_url} and uploaded to {s3_path}/{doc_name}')
    except:
        print(f'File not uploaded to {s3_path}')
```

doc_url - is the document url;
doc_name - is the name you want the file to save as on s3;
s3_path - where you want to save the file

Comment: I am going through similar approach but don't see how you make it work without previously downloaded it. can you please expand your answer.